# Nextauth cannot read properties of undefined (reading "GET")

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

```
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GET')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./auth.ts:25:21)
  page: '/api/auth/_log'
}
   9 |
  10 | export const {
> 11 |     handlers: { GET, POST },
     |                ^
  12 |     auth,
  13 | } = NextAuth({
  14 |     adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
```

im not really sure what the issue is, I followed all the docs and did what everyone else does. I hate nextauth, any help would be appreciated!

```
export const {
    handlers: { GET, POST },
    auth,
} = NextAuth({
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: 'Email',
                    type: 'email',
                    placeholder: 'john@mail.com',
                },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials)

                if (validatedFields.success) {
                    const { email, password } = validatedFields.data

                    const user = await getUserByEmail(email)
                    if (!user || !user.password) return null

                    const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
                        password,
                        user.password
                    )

                    if (passwordsMatch) return user
                }

                return null
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token }) {
            if (!token.sub) return token

            const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub)

            if (!existingUser) return token

            const existingAccount = await getAccountByUserId(existingUser.id)

            token.isOAuth = !!existingAccount
            token.email = existingUser.email

            return token
        },
        async session({ token, session }) {
            if (token.sub && session.user) {
                session.user.id = token.sub
            }

            if (session.user) {
                session.user.email = token.email
            }

            return session
        },
    },
})
```

```
export { GET, POST } from '../../../../auth'
```

I tried to use nextauth and it didn't work and gave me this dumb answer. I want to use nextauth without this error. Im pretty new to nextauth and this really frustrates me.